# Converting Time and Date represented as INT into DateTime structure in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I am currently querying the `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` table to find the status  of the jobs executed today and show them in a browser. The definition of this table looks like this.
[image: sysjobshistory Table Definition]

Here `run_date` and `run_time` correspond to the date and time when a particular job was executed both represented as `int` of course. I am trying to construct a `DateTime` type from these attributes so that it will be easier to view it in a single column rather than two separate columns.

**Example**

```
run_date = 20161125
run_time = 33000
runStartTime = 2016-11-25 03:30:00
```

The viewmodel class I have defined is

```
public class ExecutedJobsViewModel
{
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public int stepID { get; set; }
    public string stepName { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public DateTime runStartTime { get; set; }
    public int runStatus { get; set; }
    public int runDuration { get; set; }
}
```

and the code which fetches this data is

```
 private async Task<List<ExecutedJobsViewModel>> getExecutedJobs()
    {
        using(var context = new SysTableEntity())
        {
            return  await (from job in context.sysjobs
                                      join history in context.sysjobhistories
                                      on job.job_id equals history.job_id
                                      select new ExecutedJobsViewModel
                                      {
                                          jobName = job.name,
                                          message = history.message,
                                          stepID = history.step_id,
                                          stepName = history.step_name,
                                          runStatus = history.run_status,
                                          runDuration = history.run_duration,
                                          runStartTime = // Bind data here
                                      }).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

The only solution I could think of was `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(int? years, int? months, int? days, int? hours, int? minutes, int? seconds)` which is too much work given that the `int` has to be converted to `string` and then find the sub-string and then convert back to `int`. Also, handle edge case like `33000` which are five digits as opposed to time which is represented as six digits number (`183000`).

Can you suggest an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Pull the data down as integers and then convert them to a DateTime on the client.

Comment: You can import dbo.agent_datetime function in your model and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option would be to use `dbo.agent_datetime` in your query to get a datetime value from SQL (refer to [this example](https://sqlandme.com/2013/07/22/sql-server-get-values-as-datetime-from-sysjobhistory/))

If you can't do that, then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` to specify the format the datetime is in:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20161125", "yyyyMMdd", 
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var time = DateTime.ParseExact("183000", "HHmmss", 
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will not handle the case where the time is 5 digits only. I am not sure how to interpret that, but if the edge case is always representing a missing hour, you can add that using `PadLeft`, for example

```
var time = "33000";
if(time.Length == 5) time = time.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

If the missing digit is always a second, then you'd want to use `PadLeft`